# ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Expected outout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFIZ6.png)

Trying to find all URLs with Response Code 200 using pandas- grouping dataframe.
below is my code that gives the error message below :
ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys

```
url_response_grouped = log_df.groupby(['URL','ResponseCode'])
url_response_grouped.ngroups
url_response_grouped.groups.keys()
url_response_grouped.get_group('URL','200')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now I see, you don't really need to use groupby() with two columns to see all the urls with 'ResponseCode' 200.00.  You just have to do:

```
url_response_grouped = log_df.groupby('ResponseCode')
```

And then:

```
url_response_grouped.get_group(200)
```

The following code won't work because you got multiple values as your urls, but none of them is 'URL'.

```
url_response_grouped.get_group('URL','200')
```

Comment: I get this error message still

KeyError: ('URL', '200')

Comment: Try: `('URL', 200)`.

Comment: That outputs this error .ValueError: must supply a tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys.
Tried this as well and got an error 
url_response_grouped=log_df[log_df['URL'] = 200]

Comment: Use the entire answer that I have edited a while ago.

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6532/1753419077.py in <module>
      4 url_response_grouped.ngroups
      5 url_response_grouped.groups.keys()
----> 6 url_response_grouped.get_group(('URL', 200.0))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in get_group(self, name, obj)
    752         inds = self._get_index(name)
    753         if not len(inds):
--> 754             raise KeyError(name)
    755 
    756         return obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=self.axis)

KeyError: ('URL', 200.0)

Comment: I've edited again.

Comment: url_response_grouped = log_df.groupby(['URL','ResponseCode'])
url_response_grouped.ngroups
url_response_grouped.groups.keys()
url_response_grouped = log_df.groupby('ResponseCode')
url_response_grouped.get_group(200)
url_response_grouped.get_group('URL','200')

Comment: ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13692/4272119152.py in <module>
      5 url_response_grouped = log_df.groupby('ResponseCode')
      6 url_response_grouped.get_group(200)
----> 7 url_response_grouped.get_group('URL','200')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in get_group(self, name, obj)
    752         inds = self._get_index(name)
    753         if not len(inds):
--> 754             raise KeyError(name)
    755 
    756         return obj._take_with_is_copy(inds, axis=self.axis)

KeyError: 'URL'

Comment: You are still doing a groupby by two columns, read the answer again.

Comment: I get what you mean now. thank you .

Comment: Please, if that solves your problems mark the answer as right.

Comment: I do not have the enough reputation  for my vote to count :(

Comment: You don't need any reputation to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: sorry i was click on the arrow instead of the checkmark

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem is already solved perfectly, still want to provide a solution to the tuple thing. If you do want to groupby based on multiple columns and want to get a specific group,do

```
randomfiles.groupby(['name', 'age'])
randomfiles.get_group(('Alice', 13))
```

Hope it will help someone in the future!

Comment: What if there are multiple Alices of different ages - and you still want all of the Alices?